# js variable height div

Tags: javascript, css

I've tried this js code with no result.
Explanation: my page loads a div named row with a min-height not in px but in vh.
I need to set that value to another div's height, named row2.

```
window.onload = function() {
var number = document.getElementById('row').style.minHeight;
document.getElementById('row2').style.height = number+'vh';
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: did you debug and see what it is setting? `console.log(number)`

Comment: Share your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line inside the function:

`var number = document.getElementById('row').style.minHeight;`

will return you the value **with units**.

So, you don't to pass units to the second assignation.

In short, change your code to be unit agnostic, something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const minHeight = document.getElementById('row').style.minHeight;
  document.getElementById('row2').style.height = minHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood and it worked! One more thing: I need to set the result obtained with code for the row2 as !important. 
Ex. row is 100vh, with the second line of the script I have thaw row2 is 100vh but I have to add !important to the css. How can I do?

Comment: Please, if you found this answer your original question, upvote and mark it as answered. You are now having a different question that might not fit into the comments section. In any case, you can do something like (substitute the last line of your function): `document.getElementById('row2').setAttribute('style', \`${minHeight} !important\`)`. I will also suggest finding a better approach, !important alone are really a bad practice, let alone inlined!

Answer (score 0):

Use getComputedStyle and it will return the units, so you need to chop it off.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var row = document.getElementById('row')
  var number = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(row).minHeight)
  document.getElementById('row2').style.height = number + 'vh';
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#row {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="row"> boom

</div>

<div id="row2"> room

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var number = document.getElementById('row').offsetHeight;
    var numberVh = number * 0.10718113612004287;
    document.getElementById('row2').style.height = numberVh+'vh';
}
```

```html
<div id='row' style="height:150px;background-color:blue;">row1</div>

<input type="button" value="row2 height"/>

<div id='row2' style="background-color:black;">row2</div>
```

Comment: According to this website https://khaledkzy.github.io/pixel-vh-vw-converter/ 1px = 0.10718113612004287vh.  That is why a conversion is needed as done above.